# Multiple type Post CRUD

Tags: php

i want to create form with php that have multiple part and type of data. Such as:
Input Text (name,title, description,etc)
Input image (header_img)
Input Multiple image (slider)

The point is i want to create a lot of data include upload file in one page using php.
In post method, i try standard logic, upload one by one of image with if else logic, with a lot of if else logic and **different name** and insert it in each field of database (one field in one field database) huft....

```
if($_FILES['imghead']['size']!=0){
 // run upload method
}
```

And for **edit** , i try it manually, same as post method, using if else for each field. for example:

```
if($_FILES['imghead']['size']!=0){
 // run upload method
}
if($_FILES['slider1']['size']!=0){
 // run upload method
}
if($_FILES['slider2']['size']!=0){
 // run upload method
}
if($_FILES['slider3']['size']!=0){
 // run upload method
}
// etc
```

But the problem is, i think my method is not really good, its not effective and i must write a lot of code and check them one bu one with if else logic.

My Question:
Do you know how to optimize my logic to real simple code? specially CRUD.

*i have try grocery crud but i need more feature like multiple images upload*

Comment: Actually you can use slider[] instead slider1,2,3 in the form, then you can use foreach($_FILES['slider'] as $fileInfo) {...}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to implement multiple images upload with grocerycrud, in the controller you need to asign a different name method to every upload field that you need and then just copy paste the main method in the Grocery_CRUD.php file and change the name to the same that you assigned

Controller code:

```
$crud->set_field_upload('file1','assets/uploads');
$crud->set_another_field_upload('file2','assets/uploads');
```

This is the code that you need to copy, (route:htdocs\app_name\application\libraries\Grocery_CRUD.php)

```
public function set_field_upload($field_name, $upload_dir = '')
{
    $upload_dir = !empty($upload_dir) && substr($upload_dir,-1,1) == '/'
                    ? substr($upload_dir,0,-1)
                    : $upload_dir;
    $upload_dir = !empty($upload_dir) ? $upload_dir : 'assets/uploads/files';

    /** Check if the upload Url folder exists. If not then throw an exception **/
    if (!is_dir(FCPATH.$upload_dir)) {
        throw new Exception("It seems that the folder \"".FCPATH.$upload_dir."\" for the field name
                \"".$field_name."\" doesn't exists. Please create the folder and try again.");
    }

    $this->upload_fields[$field_name] = (object) array(
            'field_name' => $field_name,
            'upload_path' => $upload_dir,
            'encrypted_field_name' => $this->_unique_field_name($field_name));
    return $this;
}
```

Just paste it below and change the function name with the same name assigned in your controller:

```
public function set_another_field_upload($field_name, $upload_dir = '')
{
    $upload_dir = !empty($upload_dir) && substr($upload_dir,-1,1) == '/'
                    ? substr($upload_dir,0,-1)
                    : $upload_dir;
    $upload_dir = !empty($upload_dir) ? $upload_dir : 'assets/uploads/files';

    /** Check if the upload Url folder exists. If not then throw an exception **/
    if (!is_dir(FCPATH.$upload_dir)) {
        throw new Exception("It seems that the folder \"".FCPATH.$upload_dir."\" for the field name
                \"".$field_name."\" doesn't exists. Please create the folder and try again.");
    }

    $this->upload_fields[$field_name] = (object) array(
            'field_name' => $field_name,
            'upload_path' => $upload_dir,
            'encrypted_field_name' => $this->_unique_field_name($field_name));
    return $this;
}
```